# localStorage, i cant seem to call the data

Tags: javascript

```
var dataArray = [];
localStorage.itemListRecord = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
dataArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.itemListRecord);

var dataObj = {
    listItem: textInput,
};
dataArray.push(dataObj);
```

I am trying to save the data on my todo list, I get the items pushed into an object, that i "stringify" and "parse"...
But I am not quite sure how I then call the saved data..

And it seems like the items ain't getting to the localStorage at all..

https://jsfiddle.net/headbangz/kn0bw6yw/

Comment: `localStorage.itemListRecord = ....` is *not* how you store things in local storage.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Amy I thought the same thing, but I experimented in the console in the latest Mozilla Firefox browser and you are able to store and retrieve this way. Is this a new feature?

Comment: Ah, you're right, you can do it that way.  MDN has this warning though:  "Note: It's recommended to use the Web Storage API (setItem, getItem, removeItem, key, length) to prevent the pitfalls associated with using plain objects as key-value stores."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should work.

```
var textInput = "example";
var dataObj = {
    listItem: textInput,
};
var dataArray = [];

dataArray.push(dataObj);    
localStorage.setItem("itemListRecord", JSON.stringify(dataArray));

dataArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemListRecord"));    
dataArray.push(dataObj);
localStorage.setItem("itemListRecord", JSON.stringify(dataArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

I notice that when the script starts you are immediately clearing the localStorage.itemListRecord location that you are using, before you try to read from it. So, it will always be empty upon initialization and this script will never be able to use what is there:

```
// Data Object
var dataArray = [];
// CHANGED: I commented out the line below so that the localstorage is not cleared
// localStorage.itemListRecord = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
dataArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.itemListRecord);

// CHANGED: added these lines only for debugging
console.log('existing data');
console.log(dataArray);
```

Also, I notice that there is not any code yet that will add to the local storage, when a new todo list item is added:

```
function listTodoItem(textInput) {

    var dataObj = {
        listItem: textInput,
    };
    dataArray.push(dataObj);

    // CHANGED: added this line to update localstorage whenever an items is added to the list
    localStorage.itemListRecord = JSON.stringify(dataArray);

      // CHANGED: added these lines only for debugging
    console.log(dataArray);
    console.log(dataObj);
```

Note that, even with these changes, the list still doesn't reflect what is in local storage, because it doesn't build the initial unordered list from what is in the dataArray.  More code needs to be added for that too.

But with what I've suggested here, and looking at the output in the console log when you re-run the jsfiddle, you should be able to see that the localstorage part is working, and you can get past this bit.

Comment: I agree with what others have said about using getItem and setItem interfaces to localStorage, as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yea i changed that, it worked but what you would call "ugly code"

Comment: Agreed, this much is just intended to see if the local storage is working. I'm sure you plan to make the code much prettier before you are finished :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that API

I use what is listed on Mozilla's site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Appears to be `get` and `set` okay in this [example tied to your click handler](https://jsfiddle.net/kn0bw6yw/3/)

Check the `console` for logs

Per commentary below - exact click handler changed

```
// Add value from the input field
document.getElementById("new-btn").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var itemValue = document.getElementById("my-input").value;
    if (itemValue) {
        listTodoItem(itemValue);
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(itemValue));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you changed.  As it is your answer doesn't actually answer the question.